# Python "dir" equivalent in Clojure

Tags: python, clojure, dir

Does anybody know if there is a Clojure equivalent for Pythons "dir". Basically I need to know the functions I can call on something or more specifically for java objects I want to know the methods and properties available (I am not sure if in java they are called methods and properties, this is C# lingo).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`clojure.contrib.repl-utils/show` for use at the REPL:

```
user=> (use '[clojure.contrib.repl-utils :only (show)])
nil
user=> (show String)
===  public final java.lang.String  ===
[ 0] static CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER : Comparator
[ 1] static copyValueOf : String (char[])
[ 2] static copyValueOf : String (char[],int,int)
[ 3] static format : String (Locale,String,Object[])
[ 4] static format : String (String,Object[])
...
```

Alternatively, maybe something like:

```
user=> (map #(.getName %) (.getMethods String))
("equals" "toString" "hashCode" "compareTo" ...)
```

`.getFields`, and `.getConstructors` accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

The [`clojure.repl`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html) namespace (which is available since Clojure 1.2) contains the macro [`dir`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/dir) and the function [`dir-fn`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/dir-fn):

```
user=> (clojure.repl/dir clojure.main)   
load-script
main
repl
...

user=> (clojure.repl/dir-fn 'clojure.main)
(load-script main repl repl-caught repl-exception 
 repl-prompt repl-read skip-if-eol skip-whitespace 
 with-bindings)
```

Comment: Oh, I missed the introduction of `clojure.repl` (not that much time for Clojure atm) – good to know. But how do you use it with Java stuff, as asked by the OP? `(clojure.repl/dir String)` doesn't work for me.

Comment: True, it's just for Clojure namespaces.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't include something like `show` in clojure.repl then. Anyway, +1 for your mentioning it.

Comment: Quite handy, but not I was looking for, these work on namespaces. Thanks for mentioning them though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `clojure.contrib` is deprecated and `show` is not existent any more, I use this:

```
(use 'clojure.reflect)
(use 'clojure.pprint)

(defn py-dir [obj]
  (let [types {clojure.reflect.Field "field" clojure.reflect.Constructor "constructor" clojure.reflect.Method "method"}]
    (->> (clojure.reflect/reflect obj)
         :members ;; list of maps
         (map (fn [m] {:name (:name m) :parameter (:parameter-types m) :type (get types (type m))}))
         (sort-by (juxt :type :name))
         (clojure.pprint/print-table))))
```

Try:

```
(py-dir Integer)
```

It returns:

```
|                  :name |                           :parameter |       :type |
|------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------|
|      java.lang.Integer |                   [java.lang.String] | constructor |
|      java.lang.Integer |                                [int] | constructor |
|                  BYTES |                                      |       field |
|              DigitOnes |                                      |       field |
|              DigitTens |                                      |       field |
|              MAX_VALUE |                                      |       field |
|              MIN_VALUE |                                      |       field |
|                   SIZE |                                      |       field |
|                   TYPE |                                      |       field |
|                 digits |                                      |       field |
|       serialVersionUID |                                      |       field |
|              sizeTable |                                      |       field |
|                  value |                                      |       field |
|               bitCount |                                [int] |      method |
|              byteValue |                                   [] |      method |
|                compare |                            [int int] |      method |
|              compareTo |                  [java.lang.Integer] |      method |
|              compareTo |                   [java.lang.Object] |      method |
|        compareUnsigned |                            [int int] |      method |
|                 decode |                   [java.lang.String] |      method |
|         divideUnsigned |                            [int int] |      method |
|            doubleValue |                                   [] |      method |
|                 equals |                   [java.lang.Object] |      method |
|             floatValue |                                   [] |      method |
|      formatUnsignedInt |             [int int byte<> int int] |      method |
|      formatUnsignedInt |             [int int char<> int int] |      method |
| formatUnsignedIntUTF16 |             [int int byte<> int int] |      method |
|               getChars |                     [int int byte<>] |      method |
|             getInteger | [java.lang.String java.lang.Integer] |      method |
|             getInteger |               [java.lang.String int] |      method |
|             getInteger |                   [java.lang.String] |      method |
|               hashCode |                                [int] |      method |
|               hashCode |                                   [] |      method |
|          highestOneBit |                                [int] |      method |
|               intValue |                                   [] |      method |
|              longValue |                                   [] |      method |
|           lowestOneBit |                                [int] |      method |
|                    max |                            [int int] |      method |
|                    min |                            [int int] |      method |
|   numberOfLeadingZeros |                                [int] |      method |
|  numberOfTrailingZeros |                                [int] |      method |
|               parseInt | [java.lang.CharSequence int int int] |      method |
|               parseInt |               [java.lang.String int] |      method |
|               parseInt |                   [java.lang.String] |      method |
|       parseUnsignedInt | [java.lang.CharSequence int int int] |      method |
|       parseUnsignedInt |               [java.lang.String int] |      method |
|       parseUnsignedInt |                   [java.lang.String] |      method |
|      remainderUnsigned |                            [int int] |      method |
|                reverse |                                [int] |      method |
|           reverseBytes |                                [int] |      method |
|             rotateLeft |                            [int int] |      method |
|            rotateRight |                            [int int] |      method |
|             shortValue |                                   [] |      method |
|                 signum |                                [int] |      method |
|             stringSize |                                [int] |      method |
|                    sum |                            [int int] |      method |
|         toBinaryString |                                [int] |      method |
|            toHexString |                                [int] |      method |
|          toOctalString |                                [int] |      method |
|               toString |                                [int] |      method |
|               toString |                            [int int] |      method |
|               toString |                                   [] |      method |
|          toStringUTF16 |                            [int int] |      method |
|         toUnsignedLong |                                [int] |      method |
|       toUnsignedString |                                [int] |      method |
|       toUnsignedString |                            [int int] |      method |
|      toUnsignedString0 |                            [int int] |      method |
|                valueOf |               [java.lang.String int] |      method |
|                valueOf |                                [int] |      method |
|                valueOf |                   [java.lang.String] |      method |
```