# Java equivalent to python "dir"?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there an equivalent to "dir" in python for java, or a library which provides similar functionality (i.e. properties of objects and classes output as informative strings)?

This question is similar this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637615/python-dir-equivalent-in-clojure) for clojure and probably has something to do with  Java Reflection as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364523/is-there-a-general-backend-library-for-java-reflection), which seems to be about a more complicated, but similar, topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library that accomplishes *exactly* what `dir()` does, but you can get the same information using `java.lang.reflect`. Specifically, investigating and discovering members of a class is explained in [the documentation on discovering class members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html). Using that API you can easily find out what you need to know about the attributes of a class.

In fact, implementing `dir()` yourself would just be a matter of defining a method that introspects the methods and fields of a class and either assembles a collection of the info or prints whatever information  you'd like to know.

`dir()` has limited usefulness in Java because Java is not interactive, but if you need it for educational/investigative purposes or for application logic, the reflection API is always there.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking if using javap would be a good choice. The man says
`javap - The Java Class File Disassembler`

and I could see the built in methods by

```
javap java.lang.Double | grep -i int
public static final int MAX_EXPONENT;
public static final int MIN_EXPONENT;
public static final int SIZE;
public int intValue();
public int hashCode();
public int compareTo(java.lang.Double);
public static int compare(double, double);
public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
```

Taking `System.out.println()`,

```
javap -c java.lang.System | grep -i out
public static final java.io.PrintStream out;
public static void setOut(java.io.PrintStream);
   4: invokestatic  #4                  // Method setOut0:(Ljava/io/PrintStream;)V
   8: putstatic     #98                 // Field out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

and then do `javap java.io.PrintStream`